# How to handle special characters if values are not inside double quotes?

Tags: hadoop, hive

We have some data in CSV format on which we want to create Hive external table. Data is in following format:

```
20160708,1234,"""some text\nsome ot,her text",foo  ,bar
20160718,3210,hello text                   ,hello,x  ,y,more,columns
```

As we can see above, 3rd column in first row contains three double quotes and it contains `\n` character as well. I have used OpenCSV SerDe to correctly parse this row but Hive just parses `20160708,1234,"""some text` part as first row and misses `some ot,her text",foo  ,bar` this part.

I have following quesstions :

1. Leading 3 double quotes are causing this issue?
2. Can writing map-reduce program or Pig script to remove 3 double quotes solve this problem?

Comment: *"I have used OpenCSV SerDe ... but Hive ..."* -- do you mean that you tried the SerDe in a MR job, but not in the Hive table definition? It's available, cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde

Comment: I have mentioned OpenCSVSerde in Hive table definition.